# How to import ActionBarSherlock using Gradle in Android app?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-support-library, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying to import ActionBarSherlock (ABS) into my Android app using Gradle, but unfortunately, when building I get a list of errors saying:

```
/Users/kramer65/dev/repos/android-official/OurPackage/build/res/all/debug/values/values.xml:248: error: Attribute "titleTextStyle" has already been defined
/Users/kramer65/dev/repos/android-official/OurPackage/build/res/all/debug/values/values.xml:250: error: Attribute "subtitleTextStyle" has already been defined
/Users/kramer65/dev/repos/android-official/OurPackage/build/res/all/debug/values/values.xml:256: error: Attribute "divider" has already been defined
/Users/kramer65/dev/repos/android-official/OurPackage/build/res/all/debug/values/values.xml:258: error: Attribute "background" has already been defined
[etc. etc.]

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> Could not call IncrementalTask.taskAction() on task ':processDebugResources'
```

I'm trying to import ABS using the following in **build.gradle**:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
    instrumentTestCompile(files('libs/espresso-1.0-SNAPSHOT-bundled.jar'))
}
```

and in my **settings.gradle** I've got the following line:

```
include ':OurPackage', ':Libraries:ActionBarSherlock'
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? All tips are welcome!

Comment: remove  ':Libraries:ActionBarSherlock' from settings.gradle
 compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar' in build.gradle is enough

Answer (score 0):

The same attributes `titleTextStyle`, `subtitleTextStyle`, `divider`, `background` are defined in 2 different libraries.

The `'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'` and the support library [`'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/rev-archive#rev18) which introduced the v7 appcompat library **can't work** together.