# Unknown android attribute SherlockSpinner

Tags: android, migration, actionbarsherlock

I am supposed to migrate to Android Studio and redesign an old app. This app is using actionbarsherlock( very deprecated, I know).But, to start I need to make it work.
I have added it as a module but I have this error while Gradle Sync:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':actionbarsherlock:processDebugResources'.
>   Unknown android attribute 'SherlockSpinner'

My gradle configuration includes:

> implementation project(':actionbarsherlock')
>
> implementation project(':SlidingMenu')

The three gradle modules with the same version:

> compileSdkVersion 25
>
> buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

Comment: You can download the library from Github and added it as a module .

Comment: I haven´t express myself correctly. I have added it as a module, but at the moment of syncing the gradle, this error appears

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20564836/how-to-import-actionbarsherlock-using-gradle-in-android-app

Comment: Not the same problem, mine is well imported...